# Windows Terminal has no title bar and doesn't show tabs

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-terminal, title-bar

[image: No Titlebar]

OS: Windows 11

Build: 21H2 22000.258

Processor: AMD Ryzen 9 5950X 16-Core Processor 4.00 GHz

RAM: 64.0 GB (63.9 GB usable)

It's a pretty fresh install of Windows too, because I did a fresh install when I got another WD Black SN850 2TB NVMe about a month ago
.

I've been using CMDer / ConEmu / ZOC in the meantime, but I would love to figure out why this is happening.

I tried SHIFT + CTRL + T or whatever. It creates new tabs but doesn't show them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try two things:  (1) Windows 11 Pro is a Version 22000.282 both Insider and full Production. Terminal is working properly on my two Windows 11 Pro machines and also on my two Windows 10 Pro machines.  (2) Try reinstalling Terminal and restarting the computer.

Comment: It’s your theme at fault. What third-party start menu programs do you have installed.  Try uninstalling those and see if the problem still exists.  The title bar absolutely exists it’s just pure black.

Comment: My Terminal title bar is off-white on Windows 11 and Windows 11, so I don't think it is always black (have I misunderstood what you wrote?)

Comment: @John Sorry, just noticed that I directed the last comment at you, when this wasn't your question ;-).  You probably figured that out, of course!

Comment: @FireStarter Did you figure this out? If the solution I posted was the problem, then please accept it to close out this question (otherwise, Stack will resurface it every so often to try to elicit new answers). If it wasn't "Focus Mode", then we can look for additional potential reasons. Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

Sounds like you may be in "Focus Mode" for Windows Terminal.  That's how focus mode operates (no title bar, no tabs, but will create new tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to get the Command Palette, then find and select "Toggle Focus Mode".

Then go into Settings and see if "Launch Mode" is set to "Focus".  I'm guessing it is, and you just need to set it back to "Default".

Remember to click the "Save" button down at the bottom of the Settings window to avoid your change being quietly discarded.

Comment: Also, it seems obvious, but when you change a setting, remember to click the "Save" button down the bottom of the Settings window before you close it.

Comment: @RobM Excellent point - If you'd like to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1683302/edit) that in to the answer, I'd happily accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: @RobM Well, it looks like you edited it, but you weren't logged in.  I accepted it, but you didn't get the 2 points rep from the edit.  On the bright side, I upvoted your SU answer the other day, so that more than made up for it ;-).

Comment: yes, I realised my mistake afterwards but thought it would be too much of a faff to try and sort it out (couldn't edit it again as someone (me) had already offered a suggestion. Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: thanks you saved me ! I had the same issue here, I did not even know about focus mode, nor the Command Palette. <3